# Inheritance - Best practices for creating derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, factory-pattern

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class Employee
{}

class SalaryManager
{
    public void PaySalary(Employee e)
    {
        var bankService = GetBankService();
        bankService.Pay(e);
    }
}
```

Now, the Employee has a new property `PaymentMethod`, and the way the salary is payed depends on this enumeration.

I could easily change the Payment salary to reflect this by using an `if` or `switch` statement.

```
class Employee
{
    public enum PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}

class SalaryManager
{
    public void PaySalary(Employee e)
    {
        if (e.PaymentMethod == Cash)
        {
            var bankService = GetBankService();
            bankService.Pay(e);
        }
        else if (e.PaymentMethod == Online)
        {
            // Different implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I'd like to have an application that is easier to mantain in case new PaymentMethods come along.

Therefore, I could have SalaryManager as a base class (or interface) and have two different specializations.

```
class SalaryManager
{
    public abstract void PaySalary(Employee e);
}

class CashSalaryManager : SalaryManager
{
    public override void PaySalary(Employee e)
    {
        var bankService = GetBankService();
        bankService.Pay(e);
    }
}

class OnlineSalaryManager : SalaryManager
{
    public override void PaySalary(Employee e)
    {
        // Different implementation
    }
}
```

My concern is when it comes to creating an instance of this SalaryManager class. Who should be responsible for this?

One option could be having the Employee know about this. In order words, have the Employee know which should be the Manager class that knows how its salary is payed.

In this case, should I have two different derived classes for the Employee as well?

```
class Employee
{
    public enum PaymentMethod { get; set; }

    public abstract SalaryManager GetSalaryManager();
}

class CashEmployee
{
    public override SalaryManager GetSalaryManager()
    {
        return new CashSalaryManager();
    }
}

class OnlineEmployee
{
    public override SalaryManager GetSalaryManager()
    {
        return new OnlineSalaryManager();
    }
}
```

Or should I have a Factory class that would be responsible or the creation of this Manager class? Something in the lines of:

```
static class SalaryFactory
{
    public static SalaryManager CreateSalaryManager(Employee e)
    {
        SalaryManager manager = null;
        if (e.PaymentMethod == Cash)
        {
            manager = new CashSalaryManager();
        }
        else if (e.PaymentMethod == Online)
        {
            manager = new OnlineSalaryManager();
        }
        else 
        {
            thrown new Exception ("No Manager class found for the payment type");
        }
    }
}
```

What if this happens with different Manager classes? In other words, there are three different Manager classes (each responsible for its own thing - i.e. TaxCalculationManager), whose behavior varies based on the Employee type? Would this change the solution above?

Comment: This questions sounds too broad, and frankly it sounds like you already know the answer (interfaces).

Comment: Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of this and user inversion of control container to inject all the ISalaryManager implementations into the SalaryPaymentManager. Then all you need to do is make new implementations of ISalaryManager for each payment type

```
public class Employee
{

}

public interface ISalaryManager
{
    void PaySalary(Employee e);
    bool HandlesPaymentType(string paymentType);
}

public class CashSalaryManager : ISalaryManager
{
    public void PaySalary(Employee e)
    {
        var bankService = GetBankService();
        bankService.Pay(e);
    }

    public bool HandlesPaymentType(string paymentType)
    {
        return paymentType == "Cash";
    }
}

public class OnlineSalaryManager : ISalaryManager
{
    public void PaySalary(Employee e)
    {
        // Different implementation
    }

    public bool HandlesPaymentType(string paymentType)
    {
        return paymentType == "Online";
    }
}

public class SalaryPaymentManager
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ISalaryManager> _salaryManagers;

    public SalaryPaymentManager(IEnumerable<ISalaryManager> salaryManagers)
    {
        _salaryManagers = salaryManagers;
    }

    public void PaySalary(string paymentType, Employee employee)
    {
        var salaryManager = _salaryManagers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HandlesPaymentType(paymentType));

        if (salaryManager == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        salaryManager.PaySalary(employee);
    }
}
```